# Group by with data.table using sum

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I have a dataframe that I want to group by users and find sum of quantity.

```
library(data.table)
x = read.table('C:/Users/user/Desktop/20180911_Dataset_b.csv',encoding = 'UTF-8',sep =',')

dt = data.table(x)

colnames(dt)
"dates_d" "user" "proj" "quantity"
```

the column `quantity` is like this:

```
quantity
1
34
12
13
3
12
-
11
1
```

I heard that `data.table library` is very fast so I would like to use that.

I have make it in Python but don't know how to do it in R.

Comment: Kindly refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right for the benchmarking results.

Comment: u might want to use `read.table(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` then `dt[, sum(quantity), by=.(user)]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 gives `Type 'character' not supported by GForce sum (gsum). Either add the prefix base::sum(.) or turn off GForce optimization using options(datatable.optimize=1)
`

Comment: you can convert into numeric first. `dt[, sum(as.numeric(quantity), na.rm=TRUE), by=.(user)]`

Comment: This is correct.Make an answer and I'll accept it.Just a few questions: how the '-' dash became 0? I mean it is fine but did the strings asfactors turn it to na and then na.rm turned it to 0? Explain these tricky parts in your answer.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Due to historical memory limitation issues, R reads data as factors. When there is a character-like entry in a column, the whole column is read in as a character vector. Now with RAM more easily available, you can just read in data as string first so that it remains as a character vector rather than factor.

Then use `as.numeric` to convert into a real valued number before summing. Strings that cannot be converted into numbers are converted into NA instead. `na.rm=TRUE` ignores NAs in the sum.

Taking all of the above:

```
library(data.table)
#you might want to check out the data.table::fread function to read the data directly as a data.table
x = read.table('C:/Users/user/Desktop/20180911_Dataset_b.csv',encoding = 'UTF-8',sep =',', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

setDT(x)[, sum(as.numeric(quantity), na.rm=TRUE), by=.(user)]
```

---

Reference:
a useful comment from phiver in [Is there any good reason for columns to be characters instead of factors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351773/is-there-any-good-reason-for-columns-to-be-characters-instead-of-factors)
linking to a blog by Roger Peng:
https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

dt[dt == "-" ] = NA

df <- dt %>% group_by(user) %>%
        summarise(qty = sum(!is.na(quantity)))
```

Comment: Evaluation error: <U+0091>sum<U+0092> not meaningful for factors.
maybe the fault is that the column apart from numbers has also dash (-) when a value is not available for a user.

Comment: can u include the data into the question?

Comment: okay, so the first step is changing the dash value into NA. And the rest is same

Comment: What this shows is more like a count and not the sum.Your result is the same as if i use count in python and if i use sum gives different results.