# Is there any good reason for columns to be characters instead of factors?

Tags: r, string, type-conversion, factors

This may seem like a silly question, but after working with R for a couple of months, I realised I often find myself converting strings to factors as, for example, the `tabulate` function does not work on strings.

At this point I am contemplating simply always converting any string to a factor. But that begs the question, is there any reason not to (apart from carrying out operations on the string itself)?

Comment: Read this [blog post](https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/) by Roger Peng on the history of stringAsFactors

Comment: i would say basically, if you're not careful, factors can lead to unexpected behavior. as to `tabulate`, any reason not to use `table`?

Comment: No, I was really just giving an example. But essentially the answer (according to the blog) is that there is not really a good reason unless your not a statistician?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Could you give an example of unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factors have a dual representation -- the 'label'; and underlying encoding of the level. Which of these representations is used by R can be subtle and confusing.

One illustration of where this can be confusing is with subsetting. Here's a named vector, a character vector, and a factor with default (alphabetically ordered) levels

```
x = c(foo = 1, bar = 2)
y = c("bar", "foo")
z = factor(y)        # default levels are "bar", "foo", i.e., alphabetical
```

Subsetting `x` by `y` matches character value to name, but subsetting `x` by `z` uses the underlying level encoding.

```
> x[y]
bar foo 
  2   1 
> x[z]
foo bar 
  1   2
```

This can be made even more confusing because R can work in different locales (e.g., I am using `en_US` locale -- US English) and the collation (sort) order of different locales can be different -- default levels might be different in different locales.